# Changing Number of Items Shown using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I really like the way this works:

http://jsfiddle.net/cTuQ4/

However, instead of 'Show 5 More' for each Table, is it possible to have a 'Show Remaining Entries' functionality? Clicking this would show the remaining contents of the rest of that particular table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the click handler to the following it should show all remaining items in the table:

```
$('.more').click(function() {
    $(this).prev().find('tr').show();
})
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zhgpW/1/

Comment: Many, many thanks, this worked perfectly!!! I'm now just looking to remove the 'Show 5 More' text once it has been clicked. Is this easy to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.more').click(function() {
    $(this).prev().find('tr:hidden').show();
})
```

Comment: I would actually say that this method is better than the above. While the .show() method has the functionality to compare the current visibility of the element, and act upon that result, by targeting all elements with .show() they will all be supplied with a display:block. while that's not always bad, it might cause an issue such as if the tr has a display of inline-block and a visibility/opacity of hidden/0.

Comment: Perfect. And as a final question. Is it possible to remove the 'Show 5 More' text once it has been clicked?

Comment: call `$(this).remove();` as second statement.